# Splitting database data into class and subclass

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.1

Say now I have a table in a database, with these fields:

**properties**

```
id
num_bedrooms
num_bathrooms
num_garages
latitude
longitude
street_1
street_2
street_3
suburb
city
region
country
```

Now I would like to CRUD to it from my ASP .Net Core Web API using EF Core. So I create a model for it, but I would like to create a separate class for the address:

```
public class Address
{
    [Column("latitude")]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    [Column("longitude")]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    [Column("street_1")]
    public string Street1 { get; set; }

    [Column("street_2")]
    public string Street2 { get; set; }

    [Column("street_3")]
    public string Street3 { get; set; }

    [Column("suburb")]
    public string Suburb { get; set; }

    [Column("city")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Column("region")]
    public string Region { get; set; }

    [Column("country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public class Property
{
    [Column("num_bedrooms")]
    public int NumBedrooms { get; set; }

    [Column("num_bathrooms")]
    public int NumBathrooms { get; set; }

    [Column("num_garages")]
    public int NumGarages { get; set; }

    public Address StreetAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to do something like that? When I try to execute a read against the database in my API controller like this:

```
public DbSet<InspectionsData.Models.Property> Properties { get; set; }

// GET: api/Properties
Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetProperty()
{
    return Ok(_context.Properties);
}
```

I get this error:

"The entity type 'Address' requires a primary key to be defined."

Now, I can add an "Id" to the Address class, but it wouldnt really map to anything in the database... Am I doing this right?

Comment: You need to define the key for that entity, you can do that in two ways: first with data annotations and the second with fluent api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class Address doesn't have primary key.
You should add property

```
[Key]
public int Id {get;set;}
```

or to set already exist property as primary key with [Key]

As I can see also for class Property you will have same message.